# Готовые наборы тайлсетов для игр

Tags: c#, xna, графика, разработка-игр, 2d

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

В свободное от работы время начал потихоньку изучать xna. Подготовил двумерный изометрический тайловый движок, даже нашел подходящий редактор под него, однако осталась одна проблема - нашел очень мало нормальных тайлсетов. Художник и дизайнер из меня, прямо скажу, аховый, так что вариант "нарисовать самому" я оставляю на самый крайний случай. При попытке найти что-то в сети в основном получаю какой-то лохматый "ужос"... В общем - не нашел.

Собственно у меня вопросы:

1. Есть ли сайты, на которых есть нормальные тайлсеты?
2. Есть ли нормальные редакторы для создания тайсетов? (можно конечно и в Paint-е(Gimp-е/Photoshop-е) что-то наваять, но с моими навыками "рисования"... в общем, хотелось бы что-то более специализированное)

Пример тайлсета, если кто не знает, что это такое:
[image]

[upd] Да, вопрос получился конечно не по программированию, но извиняюсь. Больше мне спрашивать негде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы когда нибудь пробовали собрать toolbar для оконного приложения с помощью сайта который представляет бесплатные иконки от разных людей? Ваш toolbar получится не ахти, так как все иконки будут нарисованы разными людьми в разном стиле и цветовой гамме. Даже если вы будете долго копаться на нескольких таких сайтах в поисках единого стиля, то наврятли получится что-то стоящее, т.к. совершенно не факт что вы найдете даже готовый набор полностью удовлетворяющий вашим нуждам. Тоже самое и с тайлсетом. Их все должен рисовать один человек в одном стиле по одному документу, на [gamedev.ru](http://gamedev.ru) и фриланс сайтах есть десятки людей которые с радостью возьмутся выполнить такой заказ по вполне адекватной цене(реальная рыночная цена тому что вы приводите в качестве примера не больше 100-300 рублей за полоску), да и качество будет вполне ничего, если вы конечно потрудитесь отобрать достойного кандидата.

В качестве редактора можно использовать Photoshop и 3DSMax ну или Blender и GIMP если вы красноглазик. Специальный редактор для тайлсетов это плохая идея потому что непонятно чем собственно тайлсет отличается от обычной картинки.

Самому рисовать их ни в коем случае нельзя, так как если у вас нет хотя бы пары лет опыта работы с графическими редакторами и хотя бы зачатков умений художника, то в лучшем случае у вас получится результат которым можно только пугать других людей. С другой стороны с попытки с 50ой может и получится что-нибудь хорошее, но тогда вы просто потеряете время.

Правда есть и альтернативный вариант:

http://lunar.lostgarden.com/labels/free%20game%20graphics.html

http://hasgraphics.com/

http://cgtextures.com/

http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2006-08-08-n51.html

http://www.freewebs.com/teh_pro/sprites.htm

http://www.spriters-resource.com/

http://www.flyingyogi.com/fun/spritelib.html

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/272386-sprites-sprites-and-more-sprites/

P.S. Собирать игры в качестве хобби это плохая идея, так как это требует очень много свободного времени и усилий. Нужно либо делать это нормально либо вообще не делать.

Comment: +ую послесловие, но про рисование самому - не согласен, особенно о 2ух летнем опыте с граф редакторами, даже в пейнте можно спокойно рисовать :)

Comment: >(реальная рыночная цена тому что вы приводите в качестве примера не больше 100-300 рублей за полоску)

вот потому наш фриланс полное уг

Comment: @rasmisha Если бы за каждые 7 нарисованных зеленых квадратов платили бы по 100$, то каждый взрослый человек стал бы фрилансером.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается сайтов с нормальными тайлсэтами - никогда не встречал, что касается редакторов - такие, безусловно, есть, но они никак не изменяют того факта, что нужно уметь рисовать, учитывая их более ограниченный функционал, большего смысла в них не вижу, разве что, обычно, удобно сразу рисовать сэт.

Вообще, для того, что-бы научится хоть более менее нормально рисовать оные, великих навыков художника не требуется, все, чему нужно научится - базовым навыкам передачи светотени и объема. К тому-же, нет людей, которые не умеют рисовать, есть только те, которые не научились.

Плюс ко всему, если рисовать не на бумаге, можно сделать, допустим, размерность 2к*2к px, при уменьшении которой, многие косяки изображения исчезнут, главное правильно передать объем и более менее правильно светотень.

Даже если совсем не будет получатся - можно поискать начинающего художника и попросить нарисовать его, но, повторюсь - такое рисование не требует великих навыков, другой вопрос в том, достаточно ли у вас времени и желания?..

Comment: А ссылоку на редакторы которые "безусловно есть"?

Comment: Собственно спрашиваю как раз из-за того, что проблемы со временем. Лень - она вообще великий двигатель прогресса :). А искать дизайнера несколько проблематично, т.к. я не знаю, на сколько меня хватит(в смысле энтузиазма), и сколько у меня будет времени. Теоретически, возможна ситуация, что у меня на работе будет завал, а дизайнер будет вопрошать:"WTF? Ты где?" Конечно немного утрирую, но в общем, персональный дизайнер - не вариант.

Comment: Я уже писал - они вас не спасут, такого рода софт, обычно, крайне не популярный, он гуглиться, но находится на 5-10+ страницах, о существовании оных знаю т.к., в свое время, сам искал, но, по причине их бесполезности, названия были забыты, самому гуглить лениво